# Mysqli PHP fetch Value From DB that are greater then 6PM in mentioned Date Time Interval

Tags: php, mysqli

My DB

```
   ID  Date_time 
    1   2016-01-22 01:49:31 pm
    2   2016-01-22 01:49:31 pm
    3   2016-01-21 06:49:31 pm
    4   2016-01-22 01:49:31 pm
    5   2016-01-20 08:49:31 pm
```

Iam trying fetch value between two dates where the condition is that in `Date_time` the time should be after 6 pm am not sure where am i going wrong my query is giving all the ides whose time is not more then 6 pm also.

This is my query

```
$date__G_to ="2016-01-22 06:00:00 pm"; 
    $date__G_frmo ="2016-01-18 06:00:00 pm"; 

    $query_gr6 = "select DISTINCT ID from Mdd_table where  Attendence_taken_date >=  '$date__G_frmo' and Attendence_taken_date <=  '$date__G_to'  ";

    $result_gr6 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query_gr6)or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));


    $num_row_gr6 = mysqli_num_rows($result_gr6);

    while($row7777w=mysqli_fetch_array($result_gr6))
    {


        echo $row7777w["ID"];

    }
```

Comment: What's the datatype of `Date_time` column?

Comment: That's where the problem is. Storing the datetime as varchar is *bad*. But having said that [here's a workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32220641/varchar-date-time-comparison-issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps using `between` might do it? Edited now to hopefully accomodate `varchar` rather than `datetime` column as it should be perhaps!

```
$query_gr6="select distinct id from `Mdd_table` where
     str_to_date(`Attendence_taken_date`,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') between date('{$date__G_frmo}') and date('{$date__G_to}')";
```

To test this query, which btw, seems to work here:

```
create table if not exists `mdd_table` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
  `attendence_taken_date` varchar(50) not null default '0',
  primary key (`id`)
) engine=innodb auto_increment=9 default charset=latin1;

/* dummy data */
insert into `mdd_table` (`id`, `attendence_taken_date`) values
    (1, '2016-01-22 06:00:00 pm'),
    (2, '2016-01-21 03:00:00 pm'),
    (3, '2016-01-22 06:20:00 pm'),
    (4, '2016-01-22 06:23:00 pm'),
    (5, '2016-01-24 06:23:00 pm'),
    (6, '2016-01-18 06:00:00 pm'),
    (7, '2016-01-18 06:40:00 pm'),
    (8, '2016-01-19 08:40:00 pm'),
    (9, '2016-01-22 01:49:31 pm'),
    (10, '2016-01-22 01:49:31 pm'),
    (11, '2016-01-21 06:49:31 pm'),
    (12, '2016-01-22 01:49:31 pm'),
    (13, '2016-01-20 08:49:31 pm');
```

Full example

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>date between</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $dbhost =   'localhost';
            $dbuser =   'root'; 
            $dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
            $dbname =   'xxx';      
            $conn = new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );


            $date_from='2016-01-18 06:00:00 pm';
            $date_to='2016-01-22 09:00:00 am';

            $sql="select distinct `id`,`Attendence_taken_date` as 'date' from `mdd_table` where
                    str_to_date( `Attendence_taken_date`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' ) between date('{$date_from}') and date('{$date_to}')
                    and hour(`Attendence_taken_date`) >= 6 and hour(`Attendence_taken_date`) <= 9;";

            $res=$conn->query( $sql );
            if( $res ){
                while( $rs=$res->fetch_object() ){
                    echo 'id:'.$rs->id.' date:'.$rs->date.'<br />'; 
                }
            }

            $conn->close();
        ?>
    </body>
</html>

outputs
-------
id:6 date:2016-01-18 06:00:00 pm
id:7 date:2016-01-18 06:40:00 pm
id:8 date:2016-01-19 08:40:00 pm
id:11 date:2016-01-21 06:49:31 pm
id:13 date:2016-01-20 08:49:31 pm
```

Comment: if i need to add am pm wat shel i add %a

Comment: The query only selects the `id` so you don't need to add `am/pm` ~ the `str_to_date` tries to convert your `varchar` data to a `datetime` with a format that can be used in the comparison.

Comment: I am sorry am troubling u alot but still it is not showing up that gives zero result ma b if u want to see or try i can share my screen that can help u

Comment: am sorry this might sound a stuppid question but the query ur providing me is a Mysqli or mysql Query my bad :(

Comment: the query would run in either `mysql_query` or `mysqli_query` - it's agnostic that way

Comment: my bad then i tried as u mentioned and in all possible way dint get it if u can have a look that would be gud i can share my screen

Comment: i tried that is giving me the 3pm enterd values also i just need values that are after 6pm and before 9 am values that are entered between that range sorry i was mistaken about 6pm to 6 pm

Comment: ur example worked but thats wat it is selecting the 3pm entered values also

Comment: Ahhh! I think I now fully understand what you were trying to do ( perhaps not, time will tell )

Comment: Thanks mate works perect with the same how to get row count also

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM Mdd_table 
WHERE  Attendence_taken_date >=  '$date__G_frmo' 
AND Attendence_taken_date <=  '$date__G_to' 
AND DATE_FORMAT(Attendence_taken_date, '%H')>='18'
```

Don't fetch data you don't need then discard it with PHP if you can avoid it - the logic here is simple enough to be implemented in SQL.

Comment: wat do u mean by not using date how will i find the inter date between which i need to fetch the data

Comment: I said DON'T DISCARD DATA IN PHP. Filter your data on the DBMS.

Comment: What is the SELECT statement after interpolation? Is the Attendance_date_taken field a MySQL date time?