# How does BETWEEN keyword works into the WHERE statement

Tags: php, mysql, between, str-to-date

I'm trying to select all rows from a table that are included into a given time range,

Suppose I have the following table:

```
`range` ( `id`, `from`, `to` )
```

Where `from` and `to` have the type: `VARCHAR( 19 )` (for YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS).

As these attributes are VARCHAR typed, I'm comparing dates with `str_to_date`, such as this explainations example: [varchar date time comparison issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32220641/varchar-date-time-comparison-issue)

So I first define my time range (with PHP):

```
$rangeNow = Date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
$rangeTo = Date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( '+10 minutes', strtotime( $rangeNow) ) );
$rangeFrom = Date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( '-10 minutes', strtotime( $rangeTo ) ) );
```

Here as you can see, it's a range of 20 min:

```
echo $rangeFrom.' => '.$rangeTo;

>> 2022-04-18 17:02:29 => 2022-04-18 17:22:29
```

But when I add this condition to my MySQL query (to have all rows starting or ending in this range), I don't get any rows:

```
WHERE (
    (
        str_to_date( `range`.`from`, "%Y-%m-%d %h-%i-%s" )
        BETWEEN str_to_date( "'.$rangeFrom.'", "%Y-%m-%d %h-%i-%s" )
        AND str_to_date( "'.$rangeTo.'", "%Y-%m-%d %h-%i-%s" )
    )
    OR
    (
        str_to_date( `range`.`to`, "%Y-%m-%d %h-%i-%s" )
        BETWEEN str_to_date( "'.$rangeFrom.'", "%Y-%m-%d %h-%i-%s" )
        AND str_to_date( "'.$rangeTo.'", "%Y-%m-%d %h-%i-%s" )
    )
)
```

But in my range table, I have the following rows:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [from] => 2022-04-18 16:38:41
            [to] => 2022-04-18 17:12:16
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [from] => 2022-04-18 16:36:38
            [to] => 2022-04-18 16:38:28
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [from] => 2022-04-18 16:33:06
            [to] => 2022-04-18 16:33:06
        )
)
```

It should return the first-one (that is in this range) and no others, do you have any idea about why no rows are selected?

(without the above WHERE conditions, it select all rows)

Comment: you don't need to use `STR_TO_DATE()` with this date format, since the string ordering is the same as the date ordering.

Comment: aaah that's why, everything goes well, thank you so much @Barmar !

Comment: I am puzzled why you choose to use varchar for a date time value.

Comment: @ryantxr because I want to store different kind of formats (such as `Y-m-d H:i:s` `Y-Y`, etc...)